# I used OS X transformation on windows 8

Tags: macos, windows-8

yesterday i install OS X transformation pack on windows 8 after it boots the windows 8 login screen is came,but it does not shows any thing.BLACK SCREEN is displaying.How can i get it back.I want it back so important if i loss the OS I will miss so many important files.

Comment: What did you install exactly?  Have you tried booting into Safe Mode?

Comment: i install it like as a theme

Answer (score 0):

http://www.askvg.com/how-to-remove-or-uninstall-3rd-party-transformation-packs-in-windows/

The above link explains how to uninstall 3rd party transformation packs under Windows.

Comment: Anyone can find a link.  Very few people can explain how to do it.  How about provide the relevant information so one doesn't have to go to the link, and explain it in a way, everyone can understand.